# How to find the two largest values in an unlimited *args list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to be able to print out the two largest values from the list, and I am attempting to remove the max1 value from the list using `pop` method. I get an error saying:

> `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'pop'`

```py
def findTwoLargest(*args):
    max1 = max(args)
    args.pop(max1)
    max2 = max(args)
    return max1, max2
        
maxResult1, maxResult2 = findTwoLargest(-2, 30, -4, 9, 1, 6)
print(maxResult1, maxResult2)
```

Comment: Then turn it into a list, `args` will be a tuple. Also, `pop` takes *an index*

Comment: What do you understand from that error message?

Answer (score 1):

`args` is a tuple and, therefore, is immutable and cannot be modified. The following code should do.

```
args = list(args)
if args:
    max1 = max(args)
    args.remove(max1)
    print(max1)
if args:
    max2 = max(args)
    args.remove(max2)
    print(max2)
args = tuple(args) # if a tuple is required.
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it seems the arguments are being passed as a tuple and not list. So, inside the function args is received as a tuple. So, to remove an element you first change the tuple to list, remove the element from the list and change it back to tuple.

```
 #converting the tuple to list
 listx = list(tuplex) 
 #use different ways to remove an item of the list
 listx.remove("c") 
 #converting the tuple to list
 tuplex = tuple(listx)
```

You can also print the values inside the function instead of returning those, if printing is the only objective.

Answer (score 0):

since args is a tuple you cannot remove values but your function tries to find the max 2 times you can do this more easily with:

```
def findTwoLargest(*args):
   maxes = sorted(args, reverse=True)[:2]
   return maxes[0], maxes[1]
```

what this does is sorting the args (it creates a new list from the tuple and returns it sorted) and then keeping the 2 bigger elements while storing them in the list maxes.